# PySpark: Add timestamp to Date Column and Reformat Entire Column to Timestamp Datatype

Tags: python, date, pyspark, timestamp, reformat

I have the following sample data frame below in PySpark.  The column is currently a Date datatype.

```
scheduled_date_plus_one
12/2/2018
12/7/2018
```

I want to reformat the date and add a timestamp of 2 am to it based on the 24 hour clock.  Below is my desired data frame column output:

```
scheduled_date_plus_one
2018-12-02T02:00:00Z
2018-12-07T02:00:00Z
```

How do I achieve the above?  I know how to do this in Python Pandas but am unfamiliar with PySpark.

I know my desired column will be a string datatype because I have 'T' and 'Z' in my values.  That is okay... I think I know how to convert string datatype to timestamp already so I'm all set there.

Comment: Can I presume that 12 in `12/2/2018`is month, right?

Answer (score 2):

Let's create this `PySpark DataFrame` for you. You must import `to_date` from `functions` module -

**Step 0:** Import these 4 functions -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, date_format, concat, lit
```

**Step 1:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, date_format, concat, lit
values = [('12/2/2018',),('12/7/2018',)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['scheduled_date_plus_one'])
df = df.withColumn('scheduled_date_plus_one',to_date('scheduled_date_plus_one','MM/dd/yyyy'))
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- scheduled_date_plus_one: date (nullable = true)

df.show()
+-----------------------+
|scheduled_date_plus_one|
+-----------------------+
|             2018-12-02|
|             2018-12-07|
+-----------------------+
```

As we can see in the `.printSchema()`, we have date in `date` format. So, as our first step, we have created the required `DataFrame`.

**Step 2:** Convert `scheduled_date_plus_one` from `date` format to `string` format, so that we can concatenate `T02:00:00Z` to it. `date_format` converts the date to the string in format you want. We took `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
df = df.withColumn('scheduled_date_plus_one',date_format('scheduled_date_plus_one',"yyyy-MM-dd"))
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- scheduled_date_plus_one: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
+-----------------------+
|scheduled_date_plus_one|
+-----------------------+
|             2018-12-02|
|             2018-12-07|
+-----------------------+
```

`.printSchema()` above shows that `scheduled_date_plus_one` is converted to `string` format, and now we can do the `concatenation` part.

**Step 3:** Concatenation - For this, we use `concat` function. Note - you must mask `T02:00:00Z` in `lit()` function, as we are not concatenating two columns.

```
df = df.withColumn('scheduled_date_plus_one',concat('scheduled_date_plus_one',lit('T02:00:00Z')))
df.show()
+-----------------------+
|scheduled_date_plus_one|
+-----------------------+
|   2018-12-02T02:00:00Z|
|   2018-12-07T02:00:00Z|
+-----------------------+
```